# Verificando igualdades entre objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, estou precisando verificar o conteúdo de 2 objetos, preciso saber, se eles são iguais ou não nos campos principais.

A minha ideia é verificar ao inserir algum dado no localStorage se aquele dado ja existe, se existe eu devo substituir o objeto existente no array do locaStorage, se não eu preciso criar.

Exemplo:

```
Object1 {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Renan Rodrigues Moraes", COD_IDENT_PESSO: "9999160307115906859", FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "L", FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A", FLG_STATU_PARTC: "A"…}

Object2 {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Lidiane Morais", COD_IDENT_PESSO: "9999160307134108952", FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "L", FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A", FLG_STATU_PARTC: "A"…}

Object3 {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Renan Rodrigues", COD_IDENT_PESSO: "9999160307115906859", FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "L", FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A", FLG_STATU_PARTC: "A"…}
```

Caso eu insira o `Object1` e logo apos o `Object2` ele iria inserir normal, pois não haveria poré, caso eu inseri-se o `Object3`ele deveria substituir o `Object1` pelo `Object3`.

Preciso fazer isto da forma mais simples possível, se houver. O método que sei para fazer isto, é ir passando por cada tupla de `chave : valor` e verificar se é igual ou não.

Esqueci de informar algo muito importante, como isto tudo é pelo `localStorage` preciso saber se existe ou não, ou seja, não tenho sempre a certeza que terá 2 objetos iguais.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil você salvar esses objetos com uma chave única para depois obter e substituir os mesmos sem ter que comparar todas as properties? Assim você teria que apenas comparar a chave única do objeto. Isso se aplica ao seu caso?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves minha ideia é desenvolver algo para facilitar utilização do `localStorage` então, a ideia é que por exemplo tabela de pessoa a chave dela por exemplo no `localStorage` será `pes_` acrescida do código da pessoa. Isto para ter segurança que se eu for alterar um dado e der algum problema eu não perca outros.

Comment: Na minha opinião, seria melhor então você criar um objeto pra representar cada "tabela" no lado cliente. Tipo, em vez do prefixo `pes`, eu criaria um objeto `Pessoas`, ou um vetor, e dentro dele iria salvar todos os objetos pessoas. Ficaria mais fácil acessar os diferentes objetos depois, como um padrão de repositório. Ainda assim, cada objeto individual precisaria de um código único, que no caso o prefixo `pes_` acrescido com o código da pessoa já resolveria o problema nesse caso.

Comment: Então é exatamente isto que faço, porém não posso colocar a chave pessoa e o valor um array `JSON` com todas as informações, pelo motivo sitado, por exemplo quero editar o cara do meio do array, porém da um erro em salvar, com isto eu perderia os dados de todos as pessoas. Entende minha preocupação ?

Comment: Entendi. Realmente, nesse caso pra você ter segurança mesmo de que seu código vai sobreviver a erros é implementando uma pequena biblioteca de repositório. Daí os métodos CRUD do seu repositório têm que usar try/catch pra saber se o comando deu certo ou não. Dentro dessa biblioteca você também teria que implementar a obtenção e persistência dos objetos de forma única... Ou então a gente pode achar uma biblioteca que já faz isso, e aí basta você usar ela em seu projeto.

Comment: Aqui uma página listando 9 bibliotecas prontas que você utilizar com o localstorage: https://www.sitepoint.com/9-javascript-libraries-working-with-local-storage/

Comment: Mais contudo @UlyssesAlves me auxiliou em minhas duvidas. Continuarei no projeto, pois acho que o que estou desenvolvendo é algo diferente, e ira facilitar algumas pessoas na utilização do `localStorage` estou tendo utilizando comandos e estrategias para dar certeza que meu código não sera falho, e até porque eu mesmo estou sendo um usuário dele nos meus projetos. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode **iterar todos os campos** do primeiro objeto e **verificar se o valor desses campos corresponde** ao mesmo valor do campo no segundo objeto.

```
function compareObjetos(objA, objB) {
    if (objA == null || objB == null) {
        // Se um dos objetos é nulo então são objetos diferentes. 
        // Mesmo por que null nem mesmo é um objeto...
        return false;
    }

    for (prop in objA) {
        if(!(objB[prop] === objA[prop])) {
            // Os objetos são diferentes.
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Os objetos são equivalentes.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Algo importante, que esqueci de informar, é que não sei se existe ou não aquele objeto no localStorage

Comment: @RenanRodrigues nesse caso, o método pode desconsiderar objetos nulos e indicá-los como diferentes. Editei a resposta para considerar esse caso em que um ou ambos os objetos são nulos.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais fácil é transformar cada um dos objetos em *strings* e compará-los:

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142968/deep-comparison-of-objects-arrays

EDIT: como o problema envolve `LocalStorage`, sugiro a seguinte solução:

```
function saoIguais(nomeObj1, nomeObj2) {
    var obj1 = localStorage.getItem(nomeObj1)
    var obj2 = localStorage.getItem(nomeObj2)
    return obj1 !== null && obj2 !== null && JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
}
```